# Выбор картинки из галерей Андроида

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь использовать плагин по этой [ссылке](https://github.com/thedoritos/unimgpicker). Если запустить отдельно плагин то работает, а когда импортирую в свой проект на Андроид, то даже адрес картинки не получаю. В консоли не выдаёт ошибок. Подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

p.s. на iOS работает, выбираю из галерей и передаю в спрайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно кому то тоже пригодится такой плагин, не уверен что в этом но проблема оказалась в очереди скриптов в едиторе юнити, рекомендую просто копировать префабы с демо сцены плагина и скрипты в одну папку, потом всё добавить в свой проект соответственно добавить префабы точно как в демо проекте и всё заработает

П.С. В скрипте используется Меш Рендерер, я его поменял на Image

Меняем вверху скрипта МешРендерер на `private Image imageRenderer;` .

В коротине меняем `private IEnumerator LoadImage(string path, Image output)` и соответственно придаём нашему спрайту картинку

`output.sprite = Sprite.Create(www.texture, new Rect(0, 0, www.texture.width, www.texture.height), new Vector2(0, 0));`.

Надеюсь вы не потратите пол дня на такой пустяк.